# Python script to auto update files from Google Drive

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, pydrive

I want to use python script to find an updated file from google drive. For example, I have a file in local folder called setup.v.1.2.5 and I want to look for setup.v.1.2.6. Whenever the newer version is available, I can download that file like auto update. Can anyone help me how can I do that. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then when you edit your question be sure to incldue a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe the issues you are having in detail.